# Rephrase the proof "For all odd n, there exists a Group G ..."

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to construct a proof and would like to know if I have started it correctly. The proof is as follows.

"Prove that for every odd integer n, there is a group with exactly n elements of order 2."

Written more compactly I have it as:

"$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z^{+odd}}, \exists$ a group G with exactly n elements of order 2."

To prove this universal statement, I figure I should disprove the negation. Thus I have:

Assume: "$\exists n \in \mathbb{Z^{+odd}} , \nexists$ a group G with exactly n elements of order 2."

I am new to proofs and would like to know if the beginnings of this proof are sound. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One would disprove a nonexistence claim by proffering a proof of existence, in particular a concrete construction, so proof by contradiction here is superfluous: we just want a family of groups indexed by odd natural numbers $G_1,G_3,G_5,\dots$, each $G_n$ with exactly $n$ elements of order $2$.

Consult what knowledge of families of groups you have (cyclic, dihedral, symmetric, units mod $n$, etc.); do any of them have this property? (Hint: reflections in plane geometry have order $2$.)